# Using separate appfabric servers for session state and data caching

Tags: asp.net, caching, appfabric

We have a single appfabric server set up for data caching, and are considering moving to the app fabric provider for session state.

We would like to continue to user the appfabric data cache as is with no redundancy, but add a cluster across our three web servers for managing session state.

I have created a clustered environment with a "Session" cache to run beside our single appfabric server which has a named "Data" cache.  It seems like .Net is reading the first host entry as a master and assuming that the other listed hosts are part of the same cluster.

Is it possible to separate out the two caches this way?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caches are always spread across the cluster, you cannot control it. You need to create 2 'clusters' if you want one cache doesn't share the space with the other. In the confguration wizard for appfabric cache, select 'new cluster' instead of 'join cluster'.